# Uncaught TypeError when trying to post form results using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to make validation of the form with Ajax (to have feedback with no page reloads).

I call myAjax function where I pass some parameters.

```
  function myAjax(method, parameters)
  {
    var ParametersArray= {
      "method" : method,
      "parameters" : parameters
    }
    return (new AjaxRequest()).post("FormValidator.php", ParametersArray);
  };
```

Unfortunately I have TypeError after I load html page:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).post is not a function
```

What wrong with it?

Comment: All we can tell from this is that he error message says that `(new AjaxRequest()).post` is not a function. But we don't know what `AjaxRequest` is so the answer to what caused the error is unknown. Can you show us what `AjaxRequest` is? Maybe the constructor is bad. Or maybe there is no `post` property in its prototype. Could be lots of different things, but we need to see `AjaxRequest` to know what the problem is.

Comment: post() is not a function in pure JavaScript, may be you need a library or framework like (Angular or Jquery)

Comment: and in this code there simply is no method 'post()'. See the docs to know how to use it: https://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/ajax-race-condition/

Comment: @RayToal I have used this code: the-art-of-web.com/ajaxrequest.js

Comment: or maybe use a more modern library like jQuery.

Comment: @Osama I have jquery library loaded on a page.

Comment: _"I have jquery library loaded on a page"_ - why don't you use it then? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @Jeff Indeed. Thank you for your support. I still learning, so not so good with jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you use jquery in your script so do it as this

```
return $.post("FormValidator.php", ParametersArray);
```

while you use .post so you don’t need to pass method,only parameters object

```
var ParametersArray= {
  "parameters" : parameters
}
```

Comment: Ok but I think that your myAjax() in this way prevent you from use other jquery functions like .done() .fail() and .finally() which are very useful in Ajax so you have to read tutorials about jquery Ajax

Comment: yes, looks like. It is really better to use jquery Ajax in this case. Once again thank you very much for you. Appreciate that you have learned me of new way of complete a task.